# Ajax response Object

Tags: jquery, ajax

I perform an Ajax call and when done, I call

```
.done(function (response) {
    $('#results').append(response);
});
```

The output from this is something like

```
array(5) { [0]=> string(24) "mymail@gmail.com" [1]=> string(8) "Approved" [2]=> string(1) "F" [3]=> string(8) "Rejected" [4]=> string(6) "ABC123" }
```

That would suggest that I could then do something like the following

```
.done(function (response) {
    $('#results').append(response[0]);
});
```

If I do this though, my output is the single character 'a'.  I have tried .html, .text etc all with the same result.

Is there any reason this may be happening?

Comment: `response` is still a string. It seems you used `print_r($foo)` to output the array. There is no easy way to parse this in JS. You should return JSON instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is PHP file has:

```
var_dump($whatever);
```

Change it to:

```
json_encode($whatever);
```

Comment: `PHP`? Where did you see this in the OP's question?

Comment: @MelanciaUK PHP's `var_dump` only returns output like this!

Comment: I see... So it's something implied.

Comment: @MelanciaUK: The `response` gives it away.

Comment: Too many years with just `ASP.NET`. Can't remember a thing of `PHP`.

Comment: I gave the answer, use `json_encode($whatever);` And the OP has already given the processing of JSON like `$('#results').append(response[0]);`!